# my C script has stopped working

Tags: c, printf

I'm making a new programming language for fun and when I type 'print+:' gives me to insert Pfunc1plus and Pfunc2plus and when you enroll in both the number of throws me the error "Program has stopped working ..."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char sysF[300];
char Pfunc[300];
int Pfunc1plus; int Pfunc2plus;

scanf("%s",sysF);
// Print
if (strcmp(sysF, "print:") == 0){
    scanf("%s",Pfunc);
    system("cls");
    printf("%s",Pfunc);
}
// Error code       
if(strcmp(sysF, "print+:") == 0) {
    scanf("%i %i",Pfunc1plus,Pfunc2plus);
    printf("%i %i",Pfunc1plus+Pfunc2plus);
} // Error code

system("pause >nul");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `&` in `scanf` for `integers` like `scanf("%i %i",&Pfunc1plus,&Pfunc2plus);`

Comment: ^ Yes, read about memory addresses and pointers to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

```
scanf("%i %i",Pfunc1plus,Pfunc2plus);
```

`scanf` takes *addresses* to the variables, so you'd want to put an address-of operator (`&`) in front of `Pfunc1plus` and `Pfunc2plus`.

```
printf("%i %i",Pfunc1plus+Pfunc2plus);
```

You have two integer format specifiers but only pass one parameter (`Pfunc1plus+Pfunc2plus`). If you wanted to print both, change the addition operator to a comma; if you actually wanted to print the sum, remove a `%i`.

Comment: thx man, but she prints:
     print+:
     5
     5
     10 2686168